# is it possible when checkbox checked show text field in editable otherwise show readonly

Tags: validation-rule, checkbox

Requirement is I have a check box on `Case` object `ISEsclated` and one textfield is `reason`. when checkbox in not checked it's show readonly form that no one write in the `reason` text field and if `IsEsclation` checkbox is checked then `Reason` textField show in editable mode anyone can write and save record.

Comment: This is not possible on standard layouts, but could be done with a visualforce page or lightning component.

Comment: With validation rule,what you can achieve is user will not be able to change the value of reason field when checkbox is not checked.

Comment: @martin i know it can be possible from vfpage itself using rendered true/false

Comment: Can be done using JavaScript. If you've tried some code please share. It would be helpful to give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning a different record type with a workflow. This record type would have a separate pagelayout with the fields you require to be read only set as such.

Comment: i have already created validation
AND( IsEscalated = FALSE , ISCHANGED(Escalation_Reason__c ), NOT( ISBLANK( Escalation_Reason__c ) ))

But i need to see field readonly when checkbox is not checked from standard format. i know it  is possible from class and vfpage but requirment is do from standard format like validation rule, workflow, process builder etc.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with custom VF page: you can create 2 output panels in one you create inputField in other you create outputfield and then you can simply render each of them with one boolean.

VF page:

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller="ISEsclated" extensions="customcontroller" >
     <apex:commandbutton action={!ShowHide} />
     <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" />
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!enabled==true}" />
       <apex:outputText value="{ISESCELATED.reason}" />
      </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:outputPanel>

     <apex:outputPanel id="panel2" />
         <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!enabled==true}" />
           <apex:inputField value="{ISESCELATED.reason}" />
          </apex:outputPanel>
         </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:page>
```

Custom controller:

```
public boolean enabled{get;set;}

public void ShowHide(){
if(enabled==true)
enabled=false
}
else{ 
enabled = true 
}
```

Something like that, I hope that helps you.